# How should I show results of BeautifulSoup parsing in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a web page using BeautifulSoup and Django. Here's my views.py which do this task:

```
def detail(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    html = urllib2.urlopen("...url...")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    title = soup.title

    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'article': article, 'title':title})
```

But when I use {{ title }} in django template files, it doesn't show anything. I've test it and it works in shell. I've added a line to this function:

```
print soup.title
```

and it prints it every time I reload the page, but it doesn't show up in templates.

The content also displayed very strange for some other commands like: find_all("a") or prettify method. Could anyone tell me how can I print the result of beautifulsoup correctly in django templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's the result that you print out?

have you try to use this?

```
soup.title.string
```

if you have to send html in to templates try:

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ title }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following -

```
title = soup.title
```

to -

```
title = soup.title.text
```