# How can I present IMDB info in html using Django and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, django, beautifulsoup

I am kinda new to Django and WebScraping but I am having issues with presenting the info in html via Django. The function in Django does the following: first it asks the user to specify a movie genre and then it scrapes the IMDB address (https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=) with the added genre and returns, in this case, the top five examples.  I want to use a function so I can present the info in HTML/DTL like so (this example is just pure Python and the way it prints the info is the way I want it to be represented in HTML):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=comedy").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

for article in soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content")[:5]:
    headline = article.h3.a.text
    summary = article.find_all("p", class_="text-muted")[1].text
    movie_launch = article.find("span", class_="lister-item-year text-muted unbold").text[1:5]
    movie_duration = article.find("span", class_="runtime").text
    movie_rating = article.find("div", class_="inline-block ratings-imdb-rating").text
    director = article.find_all("p")[2]("a")[0].text
    star1 = article.find_all("p")[2]("a")[1].text
    star2 = article.find_all("p")[2]("a")[2].text
    star3 = article.find_all("p")[2]("a")[3].text
    print(headline, summary, movie_launch, movie_duration, movie_rating, director, star1, star2, star3)
```

And the result is (don't worry about how the structure looks, I didn't format it yet):

```
The King of Staten Island 
    Scott has been a case of arrested development since his firefighter dad died. He spends his days smoking weed and dreaming of being a tattoo artist until events force him to grapple with his grief and take his first steps forward in life. 2020 136 min 

7.2
 Judd Apatow Pete Davidson Bel Powley Ricky Velez
Knives Out 
    A detective investigates the death of a patriarch of an eccentric, combative family. 2019 130 min 

7.9
 Rian Johnson Daniel Craig Chris Evans Ana de Armas
Studenti part-time 
    A suspended lawyer is forced to enroll in a community college with an eccentric staff and student body. 2009 22 min 

8.5
 Joel McHale Danny Pudi Donald Glover Chevy Chase
Space Force 
    The people tasked with creating a sixth branch of the armed services: The Space Force. 2020 30 min 

6.8
 Steve Carell John Malkovich Ben Schwartz Diana Silvers
La birou 
    A mockumentary on a group of typical office workers, where the workday consists of ego clashes, inappropriate behavior, and tedium. 2005 22 min 

8.9
 Steve Carell Jenna Fischer John Krasinski Rainn Wilson
```

The problem is that I don't know how to manage this info in a function in Django so I can represent it in a HTML file using a loop. Basically, I want to ditch the print and go to a return render and have it like a dictionary or any way so that the result is the same as above so I can later edit each line using HTML tags and so on. I've done some research but I only ended presenting the info in a list like so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import render


source=requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=comedy").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")
articles=soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content")[:5]

headlines = []
summaries = []
movie_launches = []
movie_durations = []
movie_ratings = []
directors = []
stars1 = []
stars2 = []
stars3 = []
for item in articles:
    headline = item.find("h3", class_="lister-item-header").a.text
    headlines.append(headline)
    summary = item.find_all("p", class_="text-muted")[1].text
    summaries.append(summary)
    movie_launch = item.find("span", class_="lister-item-year text-muted unbold").text[1:5]
    movie_launches.append(movie_launch)
    movie_duration = item.find("span", class_="runtime").text
    movie_durations.append(movie_duration)
    movie_rating = item.find("div", class_="inline-block ratings-imdb-rating").text
    movie_ratings.append(movie_rating)
    director = item.find_all("p")[2]("a")[0].text
    directors.append(director)
    star1 = item.find_all("p")[2]("a")[1].text
    stars1.append(star1)
    star2 = item.find_all("p")[2]("a")[2].text
    stars2.append(star2)
    star3 = item.find_all("p")[2]("a")[3].text
    stars3.append(star3)

def genre(request):
    return render(request, "movie.html",{"headlines":headlines, "summaries":summaries,
                                         "movie_launches":movie_launches,"movie_durations":
                                         movie_durations,"movie_ratings":movie_ratings,
                                         "directors":directors,"stars1":stars1,
                                         "stars2":stars2,"stars3":stars3})
```

The HTML file looks like this:

```
{% for item in headlines %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
</br>
{% for item in summaries %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

</br>
{% for item in movie_launches %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

</br>
{% for item in movie_durations %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

</br>
{% for item in movie_ratings %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

</br>
{% for item in directors %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

</br>
{% for item in stars1 %}
{% endfor %}
{{ item }}
</br>
{% for item in stars2 %}
{% endfor %}
{{ item }}
</br>
{% for item in stars3 %}
{% endfor %}
{{ item }}
```

And the result looks like this:

```
The King of Staten Island Knives Out Studenti part-time Space Force La birou
Scott has been a case of arrested development since his firefighter dad died. He spends his days smoking weed and dreaming of being a tattoo artist until events force him to grapple with his grief and take his first steps forward in life. A detective investigates the death of a patriarch of an eccentric, combative family. A suspended lawyer is forced to enroll in a community college with an eccentric staff and student body. The people tasked with creating a sixth branch of the armed services: The Space Force. A mockumentary on a group of typical office workers, where the workday consists of ego clashes, inappropriate behavior, and tedium.
2020 2019 2009 2020 2005
136 min 130 min 22 min 30 min 22 min
7.2 7.9 8.5 6.8 8.9
Judd Apatow Rian Johnson Joel McHale Steve Carell Steve Carell
```

I have been going back and forth with this for a almost two days (this is my first project) using the following material:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvdSkBmjpbY
- https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3
- [How should I show results of BeautifulSoup parsing in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788850/how-should-i-show-results-of-beautifulsoup-parsing-in-django)
- https://blog.soshace.com/creating-real-time-api-with-beautiful-soup-and-django-rest-framework/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng2o98k983k

I think it has to do with my lack of logic/skill since this is my first time trying to use and implement a webscraper in Django. Could you please help with this? Any sort of info is well appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, guys. I figured it out. Hopefully my post will help others that are having the same issues.
Here is how I modified the last 2 lines under the genre function in views.py file. Basically, I created a zip (container) with all the lists created above (headlines, summaries, etc.) using the zip function:

```
def genre(request):
    container=zip(headlines,summaries,launches,durations,ratings,directors,stars1,stars2,stars3)
    return render(request, "movie.html",{"container":container})
```

And the html file looks like this:

```
{% for headlines, summaries, launches, durations, ratings, directors, stars1, stars2, stars3 in container %}
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    Headline - {{ headlines }}
    </br>
    </br>
    Summary - {{ summaries }}
    </br>
    </br>
    Launched - {{ launches }}
    </br>
    </br>
    Duration - {{ durations }}
    </br>
    </br>
    Rating score - {{ ratings }}
    </br>
    </br>
    Director: - {{ directors }}
    </br>
    </br>
    Stars: {{ stars1 }}, {{ stars2 }}, {{ stars3 }}

{% endfor %}
```

Resulting in this:

```
Headline - The King of Staten Island

Summary - Scott has been a case of arrested development since his firefighter dad died. He spends his days smoking weed and dreaming of being a tattoo artist until events force him to grapple with his grief and take his first steps forward in life.

Launched - 2020

Duration - 136 min

Rating score - 7.2

Director: - Judd Apatow

Stars: Pete Davidson, Bel Powley, Ricky Velez


Headline - Knives Out

Summary - A detective investigates the death of a patriarch of an eccentric, combative family.

Launched - 2019

Duration - 130 min

Rating score - 7.9

Director: - Rian Johnson

Stars: Daniel Craig, Chris Evans, Ana de Armas


Headline - Studenti part-time

Summary - A suspended lawyer is forced to enroll in a community college with an eccentric staff and student body.

Launched - 2009

Duration - 22 min

Rating score - 8.5

Director: - Joel McHale

Stars: Danny Pudi, Donald Glover, Chevy Chase


Headline - Space Force

Summary - The people tasked with creating a sixth branch of the armed services: The Space Force.

Launched - 2020

Duration - 30 min

Rating score - 6.8

Director: - Steve Carell

Stars: John Malkovich, Ben Schwartz, Diana Silvers


Headline - La birou

Summary - A mockumentary on a group of typical office workers, where the workday consists of ego clashes, inappropriate behavior, and tedium.

Launched - 2005

Duration - 22 min

Rating score - 8.9

Director: - Steve Carell

Stars: Jenna Fischer, John Krasinski, Rainn Wilson
```